# how to run cmd from batch file and go to folder within parent folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have to create a batch file as below

1) It will run cmd
2) then withing that command prompt goes back to parent folder may be with cd..
3) then go to folder jar may with cd jar
4) run command java -jar TASKApi.jar

and this command prompt should remain open

currently I am using below code

```
start cmd.exe /k cd..
cd jar
java -jar TASKApi.jar
```

But only first line works other two line does not 
Please tell me how can I do this

Comment: You dont have to run cmd.exe to run java file. You can remove the first line and save the file at .bat and run it directly. because batch files run only on command prompt.

Comment: @CodeXerox And what should i do to remain command prompt so that user can further enter commands on that command prompt

Comment: Are you trying to run this at the prompt or from a shortcut?

Comment: this batch file run from start menu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edited after a comment below:

```
:: two.bat
@echo off
cd /d "c:\folder\jar"
java -jar "TASKApi.jar"
```

To keep the console window open for further input, launch the batch file above from another batch file.

```
:: one.bat
@echo off
cmd /k call two.bat
```

Comment: pause show message press any key to continue..., I just want to remain the command prompt and user can further enter command on this, what should I do

Comment: See if the technique above suits you.

Comment: is this not possible with only one batch file